# Being prompted for the password for "git@github.com" when SSH-ing from WSL2

Tags: git, github, ssh, wsl-2

I recently upgraded to WSL2 on Windows 10 and followed the usual ssh keygen procedure with github, however for some reason git commands over ssh result in the following prompt:

`git@github.com's password:`

My checklist:

- `ssh-agent` is running
- the correct private keys have been added via `ssh-add`
- the private keys have `600` permissions
- the correct public keys have been added to github

<s>From my cursory research, it sounds like I might be having some credential propagation issue with Windows but I'm very unclear about what that might involve at this point.</s> I have generated and am hosting all my ssh keys in the linux subsystem so I don't think the above applies.

When running `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com` I can see the public keys being offered but not accepted:

```
debug1: Offering public key: ...
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: why don't you remove the `~/.ssh/` and regenerate `ssh-keygen -b 4096` and copy the same to the github. Or only remove the trusted sources file. And try

Answer (score 3):

GitHub does not offer password authentication.  It uses a dedicated service that doesn't even contain this as a possibility.  Thus, the machine you are connecting to is not GitHub and instead is an imposter.

You should remove the known keys for `github.com` with the following command:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R github.com -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Then, try running `ssh git@github.com` and when you are prompted for the fingerprint, go to [the documentation page where GitHub lists their fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints) and verify that the fingerprint is correct.  If it is not, then immediately stop and don't proceed.  This is why it's essential that you check SSH host fingerprints from a trusted source out of band.

It is likely that you have some sort of SSH proxy on your network or local machine, which could include some sort of antivirus, firewall, or monitoring software on your local machine, which is intercepting connections.  If it's a home network, this could also be your router.  You should fix that system not to intercept your data, or move to another network.

Alternately, you may wish to try SSHing to ssh.github.com on port 443.  To do so, you'd change your remote.  For example, if you're currently working with the GitHub repository git/git, then you'd do this: `git remote set-url origin ssh://ssh.github.com:443/git/git.git`.  That may allow you to bypass the network device that's tampering with your connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link to try https://docs.github.com/zh/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

---

1. `ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com`
2. Follow the documentation to add the following content to the config file, if there is no config, create a new one yourself. Just delete the suffix. Then enter the following：

```
Host github.com

Hostname ssh.github.com

Port 443

User git
```

3. Try connect again